# In Excel 2007 does the data from a formula referenced in another cell get used, or the formula itself?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function, vlookup

Simple question and more than likely a simple answer.

I have a workbook with a few worksheets, one of which is a 'data' worksheet. This information is utilized on another worksheet 'main' to fill in cell data of a few columns (using a `vlookup`). On the main worksheet, another column references the `vlookup` column in a formula  to populate itself with information.

In the column with the formula on main sheet; by referencing the cell with the `vlookup` in a formula (not the vlookup itself, but the cell/#) will the formula cell use the value from that cell or does it have to traverse the vlookup function back to the data worksheet to get the value it specifies, to be used in the formula?

Should I just specify the vlookup to 'data' as part of the formula in the formula column/cell instead of the cell reference to the OTHER column? Which method is more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will show the value from the cell you reference. Personally, I have simply referenced a cell with the `VLOOKUP` in order to echo the value needed rather than add a duplicate look-up.

Keep in mind, for every `VLOOKUP` you have in a sheet/workbook it takes time to process. If the look-up range is small, it probably doesn't take a lot of time. But as the data range and workbook grows in complexity it may slow down.